# Create an Excel file based on CSV file using Java and set delimiter with args

Tags: java

hi i have use the first code from the following post 
[How to create an Excel file based on CSV file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505250/how-to-create-an-excel-file-based-on-csv-file-using-java#new-answer?newreg=54de8f2fad2d4093a9eff9181851f19c)

but i want to set the delimiter of the input CSV file with arg for example 
if the delimiter is not a comma but ! i would like to set it manually with args an the xls file split the line when sees ! instead for comma could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate the `CSVReader` with this constructor:

```
public CSVReader(Reader reader, char separator)
```

So you only need to pass your argument to this constructor. A very basic example:

```
char separator = argv[0].charAt(0);
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data.csv"), separator);
```

It will take the first character of the first argument string, and make a `char` from it. Don't forget to add safety checks.

In this case, if you run your program as:

```
java -cp . com.example.Main "!"
```

It will read `data.csv` as a `!` delimited CSV file.

Comment: hi again one more question i try to run the code with java 1.5 and said that   in 1.5 jdk i cant run try with resources. could you please help me how to resolve this problem ? in java 1.7 works like a charm but i need to run it in java1.5

Comment: Well, don't use try-with-resources, just close your resources manually in the `finally` block.